# Extending label to screen width with grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am pretty new to python and am trying to make a really basic app that will get a person's name, d.o.b and occupation (I know how to get their input, this is not the concern currently).

What I need help with is getting a header to fully extend to window size in the demographic page (similar to on welcome page). It is being used in grid, as I need a grid for the rest of the page, but I am unsure of how to do it with a grid

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import StringVar
from tkinter import *

class main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        ## creates a menu that allows for movement and new pages for each relevant section
        for F in (Welcome, Demographic):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        ## option starts at main menu
        self.show_frame("Welcome")

    ## function to change frames with prompts
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

## welcome screen created, rather than all the options to choose from
class Welcome(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="white")
        self.controller = controller

        self.controller.title("program")
        ## window will open in fully expanded state to properly show
        ## all data without any need to maximise window
        self.controller.state("zoomed")

        ## label creates a light blue banner at the top of the screen
        headingLabel1 = tk.Label(self,
                                 text="program",
                                 ## foreground or text colour
                                 fg = "black",
                                 ## background colour
                                 bg = "green")
        headingLabel1.pack(pady=20, fill="x",)
        
        continueButton = tk.Button(self,
                              text = "Continue",
                              command = lambda: controller.show_frame("Demographic"))
        continueButton.pack(pady=10)

class Demographic(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="white")
        self.controller = controller

        self.controller.title("program")
        self.controller.state("zoomed")


        headingLabel1 = tk.Label(self,
                                 text="program page 2",
                                 padx = 0, pady = 0,
                                 fg = "black",
                                 ## background colour
                                 bg = "green")
        headingLabel1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 18)
        
        name_selection = Label(self, 
                               text = "\n1. Name:\n",
                               padx = 10, pady = 5, fg = "black", bg = "white")
        name_selection.grid(row = 3, column = 1, columnspan = 3)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = main()
    app.mainloop()
```

I am aware that it is probably a pretty basic fix, but nothing seems to work to get it like a banner on top of the window.

Comment: I have updated, removing some superfluous stuff, but most of it is requried as the frames are all connected to each other, and breaking the code breaks the app

Comment: Just based on your code, add `self.columnconfigure(list(range(1,19)), weight=1)` and add `sticky='ew'` to `headingLabel1.grid(...)`.

Comment: that worked very easily thanks acw1668

Answer (score 0):

To extend the header to the full length of the window, you can use place.

First, you need to create a header frame (without dimensions) and a few widgets in that frame.
Next you need to place the frame rather than grid it. Placing can be done along with either pack or grid.
To place the frame the way you want, use the following code (header frame is hframe):

```
hframe.place(relheight=0.1, relwidth=1, relx=0, rely=0)
```

'relheight' is the relative height of the frame that is set to 0.1 (i.e. 10% of the window).
'relwidth' is the relative width that is at 100%.
relx and rely are the relative x and y coordinates.

For any other Tkinter ideas or solutions or so, you can check out a few Tkinter GUI repositories on my Github page.